# How to Write Securely to Firebase from a Client?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can understand how to write to Firebase from a server and include the users auth token etc. But I wonder if there is a way to securely connect to Firebase directly from the client for a logged in user.

**Background - context**

The Firebase library provides the set() method seen below to allow writing of the realtime database, but there doesn't seem to be anyway for this to be secure. In order to use this code in the client it needs for the database credentials to be included.

```
function writeUserData(userId, name, email, imageUrl) {
  firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
    username: name,
    email: email,
    profile_picture : imageUrl
  });
}
```

**Question**

Is there anyway to send the users "auth token" from the client directly to firebase?

Do I need to use the rest API and supply it in the header, or is there something I'm missing about the `set()` method?

Comment: If you're using Firebase Authentication, the id token id sent automatically. All you need to do is use security rules to limit access.

Comment: Amazing!!! So cool... I could not find that info anywhere in the docs. Thank you! It totally works.

Comment: Maybe this is what you were trying to find?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-integrate-auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase rules are there for you to connect securely with firebase from client side.

Step 1: set rules in firebase database rules like below.

```
"rules": {
".read": "auth!=null", //
".write": "auth!=null" // it will not allow user to write until they are logged in.
};
```

Step 2 : you can set rules for tree level also like below

```
"rules":{
"users":{
  "$uId":{ // your user Id
    ".read": "auth.uid===$uId",
      ".write": "auth.uid===$uId",
  }
 }
}
```

[image: Firebase DB Rules]

[Firebase Rules Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/?authuser=0)